# Using the PHP docblocks @return tag is there a best practice for returning a boolean as an integer (i.e. 1 or 0)?

Tags: php, docblocks

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
/**
 * Will return either a 1 or 0
 * 
 * @return int|boolean
 */
public function getExitCode()
{
    return $this->exitCode;
}
```

It won't return a value cast as a boolean, it will be cast as an integer.

Comment: If it's an integer being returned: `/**
 * Will return either a 1 or 0
 * 
 * @return int (0 = success, 1 = failure)
 */
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it returns an `int` your documentation should say that it returns an int. However, you can describe it:

```
/**
* @return int 0 on success, non-zero indicates failure
*/
```

This allows future expansion too. What if your exit code gets changed to provide more useful information than "yes" or "no"? "no, because XYZ" could be represented with a number other than `1`, and your documentation will still be correct (which means implementations of the function will not need changing unless they want to take advantage of the new information)